# One word for tongue intermingling outside

Tags: word-request, american-english

Is there a word to describe when a couple sticks out their tongue and both the tongues touch outside in a kind of playful or sexual way?

The closest I know is *french kiss*, but it's not for what I am describing.

Comment: What do you call it? (in your native language perhaps)?

Comment: Tongue wrestling maybe?

Comment: (or even in your native tongue...)

Answer (score 2):

I did initially think I should wait to see if someone else knows a word for this, as I don't. But after a cursory bit of research turned up nothing, I think the best answer you can get is that, if a word does exist for this, it is neither widely-known nor easily found. Maybe there is some tiny sub-section of the dark web populated by people who like to do this, and maybe they have a unique word for it... but even if they did, what would be the point of using it in public if nobody knew what you meant? If you use an unknown word for something unusual, and then have to explain it, you're likely to be asked "how do *you* know this?"

If I had to describe such an action, I'd call it "tongue-touching", but that wouldn't necessarily convey the full picture to someone without any context. A quick search of this turned up a few photographs that look like what you're describing and, interestingly, one was a scene from a Bollywood movie which was described as a 'kissing scene', albeit an unusual one. So perhaps, in certain contexts, someone may describe it as an unusual type of kissing even though lips are not involved.